# Finding the lowest common multiple of a list of integers without using gcd in python

Tags: python, lcm

Input ->

```
a=[16,21, 56, 40]
```

```
**Code I wrote**

def find_primes(a):
    num_factors=[] 
    for num in a:
       # print('1',num)
        list_of_factors=[]
        i=2
        while num>1:
            #print('2',num)
            if num%i==0:
                list_of_factors.append(i)
               # print('3',list_of_factors)
                num=num/i
               # print('4',num)
                i=i-1
                
            i+=1 
        num_factors.append(list_of_factors)  
    d = {}
    a_list = []
    for i in num_factors:
        for j in i:
            d[j] = d.get(j, 0) + 1
            dictionary_copy = d.copy()
    a_list.append(dictionary_copy)  
    print(a_list)
    return num_factors
    
find_primes(a)
```

**This is the output I am getting:**

```
[{2: 10, 3: 1, 7: 2, 5: 1}]
[[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 7], [2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 5]]
```

Here is my question (**Doubt to clarify on the output of my code**):

Understand since it is a dictionary, the value for the key accumulates.

I want to have the count of unique integers from each list. For eg.
[{2:4},{3:1,7:1},{2:3,7:1},{2:3,5:1}] instead of what is given in the output from the code above.

After which, I want to get the max occurrence for each of the integers to calculate the LCM. 2^4 * 3 * 7 * 5

Kindly **advise** on how we could **improve** on the code.**Not looking for FINISHED SOLUTION.just suggestion**. Appreciate the help.

**For this question, we are not allowed to use gcd or any other math libraries to solve it**

Comment: Then is using numpy allowed? `import numpy as np` and then `print(np.lcm.reduce(a))`.

Comment: You are very close. Just put the line `a_list.append(dictionary_copy)` inside the first for loop and you are done

Comment: @LucíaBalestrazzi Thanks. Have tried that before too. But this is the output I get when I tried that.  ->   [{2: 4}, {2: 4, 3: 1, 7: 1}, {2: 7, 3: 1, 7: 2}, {2: 10, 3: 1, 7: 2, 5: 1}]

Answer (score 0):

this seems like a homework problem, so I won't give you a finished solution.

to get the count of distinct items in a list, an efficient solution is to convert it to a set, then find the length:

```
mylist = [3,3,3,4,5]
print(set(mylist))
#{3, 4, 5}
print(len(set(mylist)))
#3  


biglist = [[2, 2, 2, 2], [3, 7], [2, 2, 2, 7], [2, 2, 2, 5]]
for sublist in biglist:
    print(max(sublist))
#2
#7
#7
#5
```